# Vector Calculus, how to define the parametric equation?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Let $S$ be the surface of the cone $z=2-\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}$ above $xy$-plane. Evaluate $\iint_S \mathrm{curl}\space\mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf S$ where the vector field $\mathbf F$ is defined by:

$$\mathbf F=(x-z)\space\mathbf i + (x^3+yz)\space\mathbf j - (3xy^2)\space \mathbf k$$

I tried to let $x=r \cos\theta$, $y =r \sin\theta$, but I am confused on integration.

If I let $x=r \cos\theta$, $y =r \sin\theta$, my parametric equation will be
$\vec{r}(r,\theta)=<r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,2-r>$, but now the problem is about $\text{curl }\mathbf F$.

I change the $x, y$ in $\text{curl }\mathbf F$ also into $(r,\theta)$ form, but when I multiply $\text{curl }\mathbf F$ with $\vec{r}(r)\times \vec{r}(\theta)$, there is where I confused. It is hard to integral. Is that I make some mistakes?

I need help, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

> but when I multiply $\text{curl }\mathbf F$ with $\vec{r}(r)\times\vec r(\theta)$, there is where I confused. It is hard to integral. Is that I make some mistakes?

No, assuming you did your algebra correctly there, this is a correct way to find the surface integral $\iint_S \mathrm{curl}\space\mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf S$. However, it may be a **difficult** integral to solve in that form. Because of the presence of the $\text{curl }\mathbf F$, you should recall Stokes' Theorem:

> If $S$ is an oriented smooth surface that is bounded by a closed [boundary curve $C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2302138/525188) with positive orientation, then $$\iint_S\text{curl }\mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf S=\int_C\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf r$$

Thus to evaluate your surface integral $\iint_S\text{curl }\mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf S$, we may instead evaluate the line integral $\int_C\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf r$ where $C$ is the circle $x^2+y^2=2^2$ in the $xy$-plane centered at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

I would understand this to be a surface integral of the flux of the curl through the cone you described (not including the flat bottom of the cone in the x, y plane). This is an integral subject to Stoke's theorem. You can replace it with the work of the original field around the boundary curve, which is a circle in the x, y plane. When z = 0, the radius of the circle is 2.

$$\iint_{S} \mathrm{curl} \ \vec{F} \cdot \mathrm dS = \int_{C} \vec{F} \cdot\ \mathrm d\vec{r}$$.

Our curve $\vec{r}$ is parameterized as $\vec{r} = 2\left<\cos\theta, \sin\theta, 0\right>$ and these spatial coordinates are put into the field as $\vec{F} = \left<2\cos\theta, 8\cos^{3}\theta,24\cos\theta\sin\theta\right>$. The differential of $\vec{r}$ is $d\vec{r}=2\left<-\sin\theta,\cos\theta,0\right>d\theta$. If I did all my math right, you get

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \left( -4\sin\theta\cos\theta+16\cos^{4}\theta\right)\mathrm d\theta$$

The first term integrates to $0$. The second can be integrated as

$$16\int_{0}^{2\pi} \left( \cos^{2}\theta-(\cos\theta\sin\theta)^{2}\right) \mathrm d \theta$$

The first term should integrate to $\pi$ and the second to $\frac{\pi}{4}$, for a total of $16\pi - 4\pi = 12\pi$

Comment: thanks for your help sir  : )